SwiftUI springy scale "pop" transition
Given some shape, I want to make it pop onto the screen.
if showShape {
  Rectangle()
    .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
    .transition(.scale)
}

How could a custom Transition replace the scale animation in this example with one that uses springlike physics to scale the shape when it appears when showShape gets toggled by the user?

From my understanding of what you're trying to make, here is the code that makes the scale effect springy:
if showShape {
  Rectangle()
    .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
    .transition(.scale.animation(.spring))
}

And you can make it extra springy with .springy(bounce: <#Double#>)

Use this if you need control over animation duration and bounciness:
if showShape {
    Rectangle()
        .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
        .transition(.asymmetric(
            insertion: .scale.animation(.spring(duration: 0.2, bounce: 0.6)),
            removal: .opacity
        ))
}

